# Getting Vue.js to render JSX with TypeScript from base CLI install with JSX package

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jsx, rendering, vue-cli

#### The Setup

I've [created a basic project with the vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#vue-create), during which I used the "Manually select features" to install, where I picked the following (besides a linter):

- **Selected** Babel, TypeScript, Vuex, and Linter / Formatter
- **Selected** 2.x
- **No** to class-style components
- **Yes** to Use Babel alongside TypeScript (required for modern mode,
  auto-detected polyfills, transpiling JSX)?

Then afterwards, I also installed the [jsx support](https://github.com/vuejs/jsx) (and I verified the Babel version installed was 7, since that is required for that jsx support repo).

In my **bable.config.js** file I *added* (did not replace what was generated by the vue-cli) the preset requested by the jsx repo:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
    '@vue/babel-preset-jsx', //<-- Added this
  ],
};
```

I've confirmed that the *auto-generated* **tsconfig.json** has the needed configuration (at least as I understand it):

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "jsx": "preserve",
    ...
}
```

I've confirmed that the *auto-generated* **shims-tsx.d.ts** file has the needed configuration (at least as I understand it):

```
import Vue, { VNode } from 'vue';

declare global {
  namespace JSX {
    // tslint:disable no-empty-interface
    interface Element extends VNode {}
    // tslint:disable no-empty-interface
    interface ElementClass extends Vue {}
    interface IntrinsicElements {
      [elem: string]: any
    }
  }
}
```

In the resulting *auto-generated* **main.ts** file, the JSX appears to be successfully used (even though it is not a `.tsx` extension, as I believe webpack, behind the scenes, is transforming things to work:

```
new Vue({
  store,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

So the auto-generated **App.vue** file has this (I'm ignoring the `<style>` info), which **renders fine** on `npm run serve`:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img alt="Vue logo" src="./assets/logo.png">
    <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import Vue, {VNode} from 'vue';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    HelloWorld,
  },
});
</script>
```

#### The Issues

It is my understanding that the following modification to **App.vue** should then work (the render function is exactly what the first "Syntax" example in the jsx repo has):

```
// template removed

<script lang="ts">
import Vue, {VNode} from 'vue';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'App',
  functional: true,
  render() {
    return <p>hello</p>
  }
});
</script>
```

But instead, I get this set of errors in the terminal window:

```
ERROR in /home/scott/convrrt-component/view-play/src/App.vue(19,3):
19:3 No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Type '() => boolean' is not assignable to type '(createElement: CreateElement, hack: RenderContext<Record<string, any>>) => VNode'.
      Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'VNode'.
    17 |     HelloWorld,
    18 |   },*/
  > 19 |   render() {
       |   ^
    20 |     return <p>hello</p>
    21 |   }
    22 | });
ERROR in /home/scott/convrrt-component/view-play/src/App.vue(20,13):
20:13 Cannot find name 'p'.
    18 |   },*/
    19 |   render() {
  > 20 |     return <p>hello</p>
       |             ^
    21 |   }
    22 | });
    23 | </script>
ERROR in /home/scott/convrrt-component/view-play/src/App.vue(20,15):
20:15 Cannot find name 'hello'.
    18 |   },*/
    19 |   render() {
  > 20 |     return <p>hello</p>
       |               ^
    21 |   }
    22 | });
    23 | </script>
Version: typescript 4.1.6
```

I thought maybe I needed to explicitly use the `h()` function, so I tried this for the `render` function (sort of matching to what the `main.ts` was doing):

```
  render(h, ctx) {
    return h(<p>hello</p>)
  }
```

**That did not work.** The last two errors are the same as above, but the first error changes to this:

```
ERROR in /home/scott/convrrt-component/view-play/src/App.vue(20,14):
20:14 No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(tag?: string | VueConstructor<Vue> | FunctionalComponentOptions<any, PropsDefinition<any>> | ComponentOptions<never, any, any, any, any, Record<...>> | AsyncComponentPromise<...> | AsyncComponentFactory<...> | (() => Component<...>) | undefined, children?: VNodeChildren): VNode', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | VueConstructor<Vue> | FunctionalComponentOptions<any, PropsDefinition<any>> | ComponentOptions<never, any, any, any, any, Record<...>> | AsyncComponentPromise<...> | AsyncComponentFactory<...> | (() => Component<...>) | undefined'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(tag?: string | VueConstructor<Vue> | FunctionalComponentOptions<any, PropsDefinition<any>> | ComponentOptions<never, any, any, any, any, Record<...>> | AsyncComponentPromise<...> | AsyncComponentFactory<...> | (() => Component<...>) | undefined, data?: VNodeData | undefined, children?: VNodeChildren): VNode', gave the following error.
    Argument of type 'boolean' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | VueConstructor<Vue> | FunctionalComponentOptions<any, PropsDefinition<any>> | ComponentOptions<never, any, any, any, any, Record<...>> | AsyncComponentPromise<...> | AsyncComponentFactory<...> | (() => Component<...>) | undefined'.
    18 |   },*/
    19 |   render(h, ctx) {
  > 20 |     return h(<p>hello</p>)
       |              ^
    21 |   }
    22 | });
    23 | </script>
```

I've tried a few other things that I cannot quite recall now (explicit typing on the `render` was one, I think, both on the function itself and on the return value).

**Question: What setup/configuration am I still missing or what syntax issue do I have that is causing this to still fail to render the `return` as JSX and pass the TypeScript gauntlet?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### JSX enabled by default

You don't need to install anything for JSX support in a Vue CLI scaffolded project.
[`@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset` includes `@vue/babel-preset-app`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/be0cb95/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset.js#L1), which already [includes `@vue/babel-preset-jsx`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/aad72cf/packages/%40vue/babel-preset-app/index.js#L131).

Appending `'@vue/babel-preset-jsx'` to the Babel presets introduces errors (likely due to duplication of preset settings already in place by default). You should remove that:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
    // '@vue/babel-preset-jsx', // XXX: Remove this
  ],
};
```

#### VS Code Extensions caveat

If using [Vetur](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) or [VueDX](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=znck.vue-language-features) in VS Code, you'll notice TypeScript errors reported on the JSX lines. Use `<script lang="tsx">` to avoid these errors:

```html
<script lang="tsx">
import Vue from 'vue'

export default Vue.extend({
  render() {
    return <b>hello</b>
  }
})
</script>
```