# Remove error when passing prop to JSX component in Vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, properties, jsx

I've got a [boiler plate vue-cli install with TypeScript working to render JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68403051/369707). However, when it comes to passing a property to the `HelloWorld` component, like so:

```
export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'App',
  functional: true,
  render() {
    return (
      <div id="app">
        <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App" />
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

I'm "successful" in getting the `msg` to pass by adding the `context` for the functional component file, like so:

```
export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  functional: true,
  props: {
    msg: String,
  },
  render(h, context) {
    return (
      <div class="hello">
        <h1>{ context.props.msg }</h1>
      </div>
    );
  },
});
```

**However, I still get in my terminal this monstrous error:**

```
ERROR in /home/scott/convrrt-component/view-play/src/App.vue(25,21):
25:21 No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(options?: ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<{ msg: string; } & Vue, object, object, object, never> | undefined): CombinedVueInstance<{ ...; } & Vue, object, object, object, Record<...>>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ msg: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<{ msg: string; } & Vue, object, object, object, never>'.
      Property 'msg' does not exist on type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithArrayProps<{ msg: string; } & Vue, object, object, object, never>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(options?: ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps<{ msg: string; } & Vue, object, object, object, object> | undefined): CombinedVueInstance<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ msg: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps<{ msg: string; } & Vue, object, object, object, object>'.
      Property 'msg' does not exist on type 'ThisTypedComponentOptionsWithRecordProps<{ msg: string; } & Vue, object, object, object, object>'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(options?: ComponentOptions<{ msg: string; } & Vue, DefaultData<{ msg: string; } & Vue>, DefaultMethods<{ msg: string; } & Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<...>, Record<...>> | undefined): CombinedVueInstance<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ msg: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ComponentOptions<{ msg: string; } & Vue, DefaultData<{ msg: string; } & Vue>, DefaultMethods<{ msg: string; } & Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<...>, Record<...>>'.
      Property 'msg' does not exist on type 'ComponentOptions<{ msg: string; } & Vue, DefaultData<{ msg: string; } & Vue>, DefaultMethods<{ msg: string; } & Vue>, DefaultComputed, PropsDefinition<...>, Record<...>>'.
    23 |         // Needed to add in .eslintrc in rules a property of:  "global-require": 0
    24 |         <img alt="Vue logo" src={require('@/assets/logo.png')} />
  > 25 |         <HelloWorld msg="Welcome to Your Vue.js + TypeScript App" />
       |                     ^
    26 |       </div>
    27 |     );
    28 |   },
Version: typescript 4.1.6
```

So it is confusing that it "works" (it passes and renders the string to the html), but then gives me this error that would appear to indicate it should not work, because of mismatched types and/or missing 'msg' property, all of which is not really true, based upon the `props` definition in the `HelloWorld` component.

**Question: What is happening and how do I get rid of this error displaying in the terminal?**

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Seems like this is a known issue for Vue2 and you can basically forget tsx files if you're trying to use Vue2. At least current plugins etc. don't seem to do the trick.
Works fine in Vue3 though, fyi.

According to the types file of Vue

```
  render?(this: undefined, createElement: CreateElement, context: RenderContext<Props>): VNode | VNode[];
```

So I am guessing that using **this** in the render function is not a good idea and instead context should be used.

I believe you should instead provide a type and possibly a default for your msg prop

```
import Vue from 'vue';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  functional: true,
  props: {
    msg: {
      type: String,
      default: ''
    }
  },
  render(h, context) {
    return (
      <div class="hello">
        <h1>{context.props.msg}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

Doesn't throw any errors for me using TypeScript and Vue2 JSX.

Comment: Thanks, but that did *not* solve it for me. I was already using `context`, and I tried adding the `default` to see if that resolved it, but I still get the same error as noted in the original post.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/vuejs/jsx?
According to the README you should be able to use 
`const HelloWorld = ({ props }) => <p>hello {props.message}</p>` as a functional component then.
Does that also trigger the above error?

Comment: Yes, that is the package I'm using. I get a less verbose form of the same type of error as the three overload messages above: `Type '{ msg: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ props: any; }'.
  Property 'msg' does not exist on type '{ props: any; }'.`

Comment: Try `const HelloWorld = ({ props }: { msg: string }) => <p>hello {props.message}</p>`

Comment: Slightly different error comes up (still renders page): `Property 'props' does not exist on type '{ msg: string; }'.`

Comment: You said the `context` form had no errors for you. What version of TypeScript are you on? I'm on 4.1.6

Comment: Ah sorry I copy pasted too quickly. It should be:
`const HelloWorld = ({ msg }: { msg: string }) => <p>hello {msg}</p>;`
I'm currently using typescript v4.3.5

Comment: Well the context form didn't throw any errors but on further inspection it did complain about the syntax (not sure why it didn't throw an Error though).
The above works without any issues for me.

Comment: Changing to `{msg}` eliminates the error, but it doesn't pull the property value over, so `<HelloWorld msg="Test" />` does not display the value passed to `msg` like the `{props}` version did.

Comment: That is strange, I might have to set up a refresh project with your typescript version to see why it behaves like that. Will reply back when I did.

Comment: Well, seems like it's a known issue and I somehow didn't receive the same errors when using an already existing project in which I just tried your examples.
Anyhow the "solution" would be to use [vue-tsx-support](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cli-plugin-tsx-support).

Comment: Ugghh. I wasn't able to get any different results with the `vue-tsx-support` plugin either :-(.

Comment: I'm sorry. That's a bummer, but like I said it seems to be a known issue and you probably have to forget about tsx for Vue2.
If you don't explicitly have to use Vue2 I'd recommend using Vue3 instead.
I've been using [tsx](https://github.com/vuejs/jsx-next) in Vue3 successfully for a while now and it works nicely for typing props etc.
Only drawback is that components written in Vue3 JSX are not downwards compatible (they're created using createVNode which is not a function that exists in Vue2).